# Change css on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, border, blur

So I have some required `inputs` and some normal inputs(non-required). The required ones have red `border` and the normal ones don't.

```
<input type='text'>
<br>
<input type='text' class="required">
```

I want the required input's to lose the border and become normal ones when they have some content inside, but i want them back with the red border if the content is set to empty.

I've already kinda achieved this but the script i'm using is affecting also the normal input's which i don't want to have the border changed to red.

```
//sets value back to empty when focused
$('input:text').focus(function () {
    $(this).val('');
});

//changes the border of the required inputs depending if their content is empty or not
$('input:text').blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $(this).css({
            border: '1px solid #c4c4c4',
            color: '#000000'
        });
    } else {
        $(this).css({
            border: '2px solid #FF0000',
            color: '#FF0000'
        });
    }
});
```

[Check this JSFiddle for better understanding, please](http://jsfiddle.net/G9fgm/)

Comment: Why are you emptying the field on focus? That's pretty annoying for users who want to correct a typo in an existing value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/G9fgm/4/)

```
$('input:text.required').blur(

function () {
    if (this.value != '') {
        $(this).css({
            border: '1px solid #c4c4c4',
            color: '#000000'
        });
    } else {
        $(this).css({
            border: '2px solid #FF0000',
            color: '#FF0000'
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this code:

```
$('input:text').blur(
```

with this:

```
$(':text.required').blur(
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/G9fgm/2/)

Answer (score 0):

just select the input having required class

```
$('input.required').blur(
    .....
```

you are selecting `input:text` this seletcs all text input

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G9fgm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you were suppose identify the requires inputs with an **Id**.existing code is with respect to all input text boxes, hence the problem.

```
//sets value back to empty when focused
 $('input:text').focus(

function () {
   $(this).val('');
});

//changes the border of the required inputs depending if their content is empty or not
  $('input:text #req').blur(    //modified line

function () {
  if ($(this).val() != '') {
      $(this).css({
          border: '1px solid #c4c4c4',
          color: '#000000'
      });
  } else {
    $(this).css({
        border: '2px solid #FF0000',
         color: '#FF0000'
    });
  }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/G9fgm/5/)